# Iterating over df to create nested dict in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a customer df with columns such as ID, email, job_role, etc.

I would like to create a dict with the following structure:

```
{id1 : { 'email':'email_address@gmail.com', 'job_role':'manager', ...}
 id2: { 'email':'email_address2@aol.com', 'job_role':'associate', ...}}
```

Is there an easy/iterable way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the purpose of the `to_dict` method, with the 'index' argument: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html

```
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame({'email':['email_address@gmail.com','email_address2@aol.com'],'job_role':['manager','associate']})
>>> df
                     email   job_role
0  email_address@gmail.com    manager
1   email_address2@aol.com  associate
>>> df.to_dict('index')
{0: {'email': 'email_address@gmail.com', 'job_role': 'manager'}, 1: {'email': 'email_address2@aol.com', 'job_role': 'associate'}}
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. One thing to mention, is that in order to succeed I needed to set_index() on the ID column of the df I was using.